# Eclipse - PDT & SVN is MIA (missing)

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have following packages installed on my Scientific Linux release 6.0 (Carbon):

```
eclipse-svnkit-1.3.0-3.el6.x86_64
eclipse-rcp-3.6.1-6.13.el6.x86_64
eclipse-swt-3.6.1-6.13.el6.x86_64
eclipse-platform-3.6.1-6.13.el6.x86_64
eclipse-subclipse-1.6.5-6.el6.x86_64
eclipse-phpeclipse-1.2.1-6.el6.noarch
svnkit-1.3.0-3.el6.x86_64
```

Everything was working fine uppon installation, I haven't used my Eclipse in a while and now when I tried using I'm missing Subversion part (subclipse). I've tried removing and reinstalling all of these packages but that didn't help me solve my problem, so I'm kind of lost at this point... any ideas?

here is few more related packages that I have installed:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo grep javahl /var/log/yum.log 
May 14 14:01:38 Installed: subversion-javahl-1.6.11-2.el6_0.3.x86_64
Jun 09 09:57:50 Updated: subversion-javahl-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -qa | grep ^subversion
subversion-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64
subversion-javahl-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Whenever I try to do File-New I only get "General" and "CVS" (I think you get them when installing regular eclipse, I dont get PHP or SVN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run as root

```
$ su -
# eclipse -clean
```